ROS2 Windows 10 Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for custom msg/srv
I was following this tutorial about implementing custom msg/srv files but I'm getting an error whenever I build my "talker" package.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2_test\install\lib\publisher_py\listener-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('publisher-py==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'listener')())
  File "C:\dev\ros2_test\install\Lib\site-packages\publisher_py\subscriber_member_function.py", line 25, in main
    minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()
  File "C:\dev\ros2_test\install\Lib\site-packages\publisher_py\subscriber_member_function.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
  File "C:\Users\PMF\Documents\ROS\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\node.py", line 1625, in create_subscription
    check_is_valid_msg_type(msg_type)
  File "C:\Users\PMF\Documents\ROS\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\type_support.py", line 35, in check_is_valid_msg_type
    check_for_type_support(msg_type)
  File "C:\Users\PMF\Documents\ROS\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\type_support.py", line 29, in check_for_type_support
    msg_or_srv_type.__class__.__import_type_support__()
  File "C:\dev\ros2_test\install\Lib\site-packages\tutorial_interfaces\msg\_num.py", line 36, in __import_type_support__
    module = import_type_support('tutorial_interfaces')
  File "C:\Users\PMF\Documents\ROS\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\rosidl_generator_py\import_type_support_impl.py", line 48, in import_type_support
    raise UnsupportedTypeSupport(pkg_name)
rosidl_generator_py.import_type_support_impl.UnsupportedTypeSupport: Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for package 'tutorial_interfaces'
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

publisher file:
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from tutorial_interfaces.msg import Num


class MinimalPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Num, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = Num()
        msg.data = self.i
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%d"' % msg.data)
        self.i += 1


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)

    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

publisher's package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>publisher_py</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Test python publisher</description>
  <maintainer email="PMF@todo.todo">PMF</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>tutorial_interfaces</exec_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(tutorial_interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Num.msg"
  "msg/Sphere.msg"
  "srv/AddThreeInts.srv"
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs # Add packages that above messages depend on, in this case geometry_msgs for Sphere.msg
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()

tutorial interface's package.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>tutorial_interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="PMF@todo.todo">PMF</maintainer>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
  
  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>

</package>

I've seen from this similar post about how this could potentially be a Python version problem, but I checked that my ROS2 uses Python3.8 and that I also use Python3.8, so I don't think it's that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
I was building my package when I noticed that the terminal outputted this during the build:
-- Found Python3: C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/python3.12.exe (found version "3.12.4") found components: Interpreter

I assumed that my ROS2 was using Python3.8 because there was a folder in ROS2 that was named python3.8, but the compiler seems to disagree.
I tried looking into that directory but it didn't even exist.
My Python version is 3.8 and the interpreter I use for VSCODE is also 3.8 so I could probably assume that the error is from here according to the above link.
Can anyone tell me how to make my ROS2 compiler use Python 3.8? Thanks in advance.
